# how to enable SSL connections in alamofire

Tags: ssl, swift, alamofire

how to enable ssl connections just as the AFNetworking did:

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kHostName]]; 
self.manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

I had neither username nor password in my case, just a `post request` like this

```
https://domain/request
```

and the parameter:

```
email=123@abc.com
```

**UPDATED**

I had solved this case since I changed the parameter encoding form `.JSON` to `.URL`.

Comment: can you share code for how to enable AuthenticationChallenge for credentialUser and password to work with alamofire

Comment: @Max In my case, there was no any username or password, I think you can check the answer by marius below, or check the Alamofire document. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
         .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
         .response {(request, response, _, error) in
             println(response)
         }
```

From https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.

Invalid HTTPS certificates feature does not seem to be available yet - https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/116 .

Comment: I had neither username nor password in my case,so the tips come from the document dose not help, and I had solved now, the Alamofire works well since I changed the parameter encoding from .JSON to .URL.